# Excluding An IP from Rewrite Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a rewrite rule for redirecting to maintenance page

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wh_client1/index.html
RewriteRule ^ /wh_client1/index.html [R=301]
```

It is working fine but I want to exclude one IP to which above rule should not apply

Is it Possible?

Comment: my question not Clear?

Answer (score 4):

In order to exclude an IP from accessing a page, assuming you are using apache, you could use a clause like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.22\.33\.44$ [NC]
```

In this answer, `11.22.33.44` is an example. Replace it with your actual IP address.

Comment: Thanks @yuan it might work too, but **RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^17\.2\.10\.8$'** Worked for me.

Comment: Note remote_host will only work if there is no reverse dns set -host is the hostname not the ip

Comment: Why the `[NC]`?! I would imagine that will slow down your regex engine so not having it would be faster. All IPs will just be digits unless you are using IPv6 and in that case, as far as I know, it's all always lowercase (canonicalization requirement).